# Spring Security, Method Security annotation (@Secured ) is not working (java config)

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to set up a method security annotation using @Secured("ADMIN") (without any XML, only java config, Spring Boot). But access via roles does not work.

Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

.....

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").fullyAuthenticated().and()
                .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

.....

}
```

I want restrict access to the method of the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/groups")
public class GroupController {

    @Autowired
    private GroupService groupService;

    @Secured("ADMIN")
    @RequestMapping
    public List<Group> list() {
        return groupService.findAll();
    }

}
```

Restrict access by the url is working, with:

```
.antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
```

Maybe I forgot to specify that I want restrict by roles?

**UPD:**
By the rules, At what layer must be `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")` in Controller layer or in Service layer?

Comment: What does not work ? Is the browsers not trying to authenticate you ? Does it ignore the credentials you provide ? By the way: you should also post where you map your user to the admin group, perhaps this is the problematic area.

Comment: The authentication working correctly, but any user with any role have access to "/api/groups"

Comment: Where are you setting the ROLE 'ADMIN', can you show me that??

Comment: Despite the fact that role is defined correctly: `org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken: Principal: SecurityUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ADMIN`

Comment: here you see that authority was actually `ADMIN` and not `ROLE_ADMIN`. Because RoleVoter checks authorities with starting with `ROLE_` it can't find your authority (which is `ADMIN`) and thus abstains

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue was solved.

I add `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class AppSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
}
```

And in controller i changed `@Secured("ADMIN")` to `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")`

Comment: @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN") should equally work with the `securedEnabled=true` flag set in `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation as per the answer by @user1210708.

Comment: `securedEnabled=true` didn't work for me: Spring granted access to the controller regardless of the user roles. Instead I used `prePostEnabled = true` and replaced `@Secured` with `@PreAuthorize` and it worked. Magic!

Comment: @vadipp make sure you also add the `ROLE_` preffix when setting the authorities. for example: `new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getName())`.  that worked for me.

Answer (score 62):

Kindly add this

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
```

This element is used to enable annotation-based security in your application (by setting the appropriate attributes on the element), and also to group together security pointcut declarations which will be applied across your entire application context specifically for `@Secured`.
Hence your code should look like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class AppSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{..
```

Comment: made the edit for specifically securedEnabled = true

Comment: i am try this, but this does not work correctly, ie spring response "Access denied"

Comment: Let's do some analysis, any surviving reason of adding  @RequestMapping below Secured("ADMIN")

Comment: Any progress? Did you try removing that @RequestMapping below @Secured("ADMIN")

Comment: Kindly let  me know if you made any progress or if the solution is fixed with the help of the proposed solution then kindly close the question by accepting the answer

Comment: i can't remove `@RequestMapping`, because this method must be  mapped by url

Comment: But did you try to remove the @RequestMapping and see what happens, we are doing this to analyse the problem cause

Comment: 1) if i remove `@RequestMapping` the spring response: "status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed".
2) the user got role "ADMIN" and what value in annotation @Secured must be: "ADMIN" or "ROLE_ADMIN"?

Comment: Remove it from @RequestMapping from the class level and @RequestMapping("/api/groups") at the method level including Secured

Comment: any way to bypass this on tests?

Answer (score 17):

I know this thread is quite old and my answer alludes to portions of the answers by various people in this thread; but here is a list combined list of pitfalls and answers:

1. When using @Secured, and the role name is (e.g.) ADMIN; this means an annotation of @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN").
2. WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter must have @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
3. As with most Spring related proxies, make sure that the class and the secured methods are not in any way final.  For Kotlin this means "open" every method as well as the class.
4. When the class and its methods are virtual ("open"), then there is no implied need for an interface.

Here is part of a working Kotlin example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1")

    open class DiagnosticsController {
        @Autowired
        lateinit var systemDao : SystemDao

        @RequestMapping("ping", method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET))
        @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
        open fun ping(request : HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse) : String { ... 
    }
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
open class WebSecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
```

Regards

Comment: In kotlin you need to have the controller class and the methods open, otherwise you get --> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class

Answer (score 16):

There may be many reasons for which method security on a controller does not work.

First because it is never cited as example in Spring Security manual ... joking but it may be tricky to take Spring tools where they do not want to go.

More seriously, you should enable method security as already said by @Mudassar. The manual says :

*We can enable annotation-based security using the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation on any `@Configuration` instance. For example, the following would enable Spring Security’s `@Secured` annotation.*

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig {
   // ...
}
```

Note that Mudassar's answer is correct till here.

But method security is based on AOP, which by default uses JDK proxying on **interfaces**. That's the reason why all examples applies method security on the service layer, because the service classes are normally injected in controllers as interfaces.

You can of course use it on controller layer, but :

- either all your controllers implement interfaces for you all `@Secured` annotated methods
- or you must switch to class proxying

The rule that I try to follow is :

- if I want to secure an URL, I stick to HTTPSecurity
- if I need to allow finer grained access, I add security at service layer

Comment: The disadvantage to just use HTTP security is that usually URLs are defined in controllers by using request related annotations (such as `@GetMapping`, `@POST`, etc.). However, URL to role mappings are being placed in a separate HTTP security configuration class. Once a URL changes in a controller, it effectively loses its current role requirements unless you change the URL in your security configuration as well. If methods are annotated, they cannot accidently lose role information.

Answer (score 3):

I want to share my decision, may be it will be helpful.

Used **spring mvc** + **spring security**, version `4.2.9.RELEASE`

For example, i have a Service with method annotated @Secured

```
@Secured("ACTION_USER_LIST_VIEW")
List<User> getUsersList();
```

But, it didn't work, because **GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration** has inside method.

```
protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager()
```

in which initialized the `new RoleVoter()` with default `rolePrefix = "ROLE_";` *(this makes it impossible to use beans to set your rolePrefix)* that give to us not working annotations, because **RoleVoter** expects annotation value which starts with **'ROLE_'**

For resolving this problem i override **GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration** like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class AppMethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters = new ArrayList<>();
        ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice expressionAdvice = new ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice();
        expressionAdvice.setExpressionHandler(getExpressionHandler());
        decisionVoters.add(getRoleVoter());
        decisionVoters.add(new AuthenticatedVoter());
        return new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
    }

    private RoleVoter getRoleVoter() {
        RoleVoter e = new RoleVoter();
        e.setRolePrefix("");
        return e;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are the man. This code works, now @Secured works without ROLE_ preffix.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use @secured(ROLE_ADMIN) instead of @secured(ADMIN). You are required to write **"ROLE_"** infront of your role name. Please find the example mentioned below which is making sure only a user with Admin role can access list() method.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/groups")
public class GroupController {

    @Autowired
    private GroupService groupService;

    @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
    @RequestMapping
    public List<Group> list() {
        return groupService.findAll();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should register your AppSecurityConfiguration to same context as WebMvcConfig (that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter).

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext mvcContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();      
mvcContext.register(WebMvcConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Spend couple of hours, finally figured out. Method level security work for service layer with spring security version 5.7.8 version.

I moved @PreAuthorize annotation to service class from controller class then worked for me.