# spring boot get controller class out of ServletRequest in a AuthorizationFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlet-filters

Heee there,

right now I am totally stuck. I spend hours asking google but I haven't found any solution or approach yet. Maybe you guys can help me.

**Some background information:**

I am developing a microservice into an existing microservice infrastructure. I want to use spring boot and connect the service to our existing authentication service. There are plenty of other jax rs microservices which are already connected to it. I started with an authentication and an authorization filter. The authentication filter works perfectly.

**The problem:**

I want to use my own "Secured" annotation like in the other services.
So there are some annotated resource methods in controllers like this example one:

```
    @Secured({Role.ADMIN,...})
    @RequestMapping(value = "/interfaces", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ExportInvoiceInterfaceResponseRepListWrapper> getAll() {
       ...
    }
```

so when the following filter gets triggered I want to read the roles of the annotated controller method. In jax rs I just used the Class ResourceInfo to do so. As you may know I can't use this class in a default spring boot setup. Is there any way to get the class "the spring boot way"?

```
    public class AuthorizationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        // Get the resource class which matches with the requested URL
        // Extract the roles declared by it
        Class<?> resourceClass = resourceInfo.getResourceClass();
        List<Role> classRoles = extractRoles(resourceClass);
...

}
```

Any help would be awesome. Thank you in advanced.

Cheers
Frank

Comment: so this doesn't answer your question at all but i find this interesting. especially the 2nd answer which speaks to using security at the service level rather than controller level & rules of thumb to follow. [Spring security method annotation secured is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186826/spring-security-method-security-annotation-secured-is-not-working-java-con)