# Spring Security, annotation @Secured is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using **Spring MVC**.

The **@Secured** annotation does not work.

I've tried many options and nothing seems to work. Tell me, what am I doing wrong **?**

I was looking at this page - [Spring Security, Method Security annotation (@Secured ) is not working (java config)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186826/spring-security-method-security-annotation-secured-is-not-working-java-con) it didn't help me.

.
.
.

This is my github code.
https://github.com/MyTestPerson/securede

**Personal.class**

```
    @Controller
    public class Personal {


        @GetMapping(value = "/personal")
        public ModelAndView personalGet () {

            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/personal");

            modelAndView.addObject("msg", myMsg());

            return modelAndView;

        }



        @Secured(value = {"ROLE_ADMIN"})
        private String myMsg() {

            return "Hello USER!!!";

        }

    }
```

**SecurityConfig.class**

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        @Autowired
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


        @Autowired
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        }


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http

                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .mvcMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .mvcMatchers("/personal/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
                    .mvcMatchers("/login").anonymous()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()

                    .and()
                    .formLogin()

                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true);


        }


    }
```

**RootConfig.class**

```
    @EnableWebMvc
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("com.securede.security")
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
    public class RootConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    }
```

**UserDetail.class**

```
    @Service
    public class UserDetail implements UserDetailsService {

        @Autowired
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                    "user",
                    passwordEncoder.encode("user"),
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    getAuthorities());
        }

        private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(){

            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<>();
            authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

            return authList;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call the *secured* method at

```java
modelAndView.addObject("msg", myMsg());
```

you are actually calling the local method (as if you were calling `this.myMsg()`), completely bypassing annotation processing by Spring Security.

You can achieve your goal if you move the `myMsg()` method to the service layer (i.e. in `UserDetailsService`), inject it into your controller and then call the method:

```java
@Controller
public class Personal {


    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/personal")
    public ModelAndView personalGet () {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/personal");
        modelAndView.addObject("msg", userDetailsService.myMsg());
        return modelAndView;

    }

}
```

Comment: right: Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4396530/280244 - this answer was written for transactions, but it is the same for security

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want, you can also use `@PreAuthorization` annotation as well on controller method level.
Example:

```
@PreAuthorization("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") 
@GetMapping(value = "/personal")
public ModelAndView personalGet () {..}
```

The Spring can not apply annotation based logic on the private methods.