Spring security authorization not working
I created a pure Spring web application for learning purposes. It uses a simple database, where there are two roles: "Admin" and "User". It has a /login part where I can log in. Based on the role the user is forwarded to different pages. With "User" role it is a simple greeting page where the user can logout, and that's it. With "Admin" role the user get a list of all the users and he can edit or delete them, or create a new user. The adding and editing happens with using the same form and it is at /add_or_edit, this is used by its controller.
The goal would be that /add_or_edit is restricted to "Admin" usage only. Right now I can reach it without logging in, and also with "User" role. I could use a simple WebFilter to redirect to /login or user home based on the content of the session but I would like to achieve something similar with Spring security authorization. The Spring security logging / authentication seems to work fine but I wasn't able to create a good one for authorization.
I created a SecurityConfig class:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/add_or_edit", "/add_or_edit/**").hasRole("Admin")
                    .antMatchers("/home","/home/**").hasAnyRole("User", "Admin")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
    }
}

It is added to a WebAppInitializer (extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer) .
Here, at configure I also tried to just prohibit GET and POST before.
For UserDetails I use custom-made wrapper class, this one:
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    private User user;

    public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return user.getRole() == null ?
                Collections.emptyList() :
                Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + user.getRole().getName()));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getLogin();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}

The LoginController is this one:
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LoginController.class);
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String showLoginPage() {
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String handleLogin(@RequestParam("login") String login,
                              @RequestParam("password") String password,
                              HttpSession session) {

        try {
            // Create an Authentication object
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login, password));

            // Authentication successful, set UserDetails in session if needed
            CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
            session.setAttribute(USER, userDetails.getUser());

            // Redirect to home page after successful login
            return "redirect:/home";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            session.setAttribute("error", "Login or Password is not appropriate. Please try it again.");
            return "login";
        }
    }
}

And this is the CustomUserDetailsService:
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDao.findByLogin(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
        }

        System.out.println("User " + username + " found with role: " + user.getRole().getName());
        CustomUserDetails customUserDetails = new CustomUserDetails(user);
        customUserDetails.getAuthorities().forEach(authority -> {
            System.out.println("Authority: " + authority.getAuthority());
        });
        return new CustomUserDetails(user);
    }
}

Additional information: configure is reached:

Please consider the fact that it is my first attempt to do something like this. I'm 100 percents sure there are many faulty things there. I thought these are maybe enough to find my fault but if I can provide anything that could be useful here, please let me know.
Thank you very much for your help in advance.

It looks like your SecurityConfig is not loading. Set a breakpoint at the 2nd line in configure(), start the app and see if you hit the breakpoint. Depending on the result I will ask you more.

@John Williams Thank you for writing. It will sound strange but right now Tomcat is not set on this machine. It is run from docker-compose. I can't tell how I could set a breakpoint in this case but I put a printing there (,,SOMETHING IS HERE'') and logs shows that it reaches that point. I put a screenshot about it at the bottom of the question.

All looks good, it's loading the security rules. I will have to think about why it isn't using them. The logs may help someone else answer the question. Enable logging for spring security and make a call to/add_or_edit. In application.properties (or yml equivalent): logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

Thank you. Isn't application.properties a Spring Boot exclusive things (maybe not, I'm just asking) without further setting? It is a pure Spring application. I tried it, though, it didn't show more. I use log4j2, I set these things in its properties file:
Enable debug logging for Spring Security
logger.springSecurity.name = org.springframework.security
logger.springSecurity.level = DEBUG
Optionally, add another logger for web requests
logger.web.name = org.springframework.web
logger.web.level = DEBUG

Maybe it's solved, I'm not sure. I found this randomly:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186826/spring-security-method-security-annotation-secured-is-not-working-java-con
I used EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true) at SecurityConfig and Secured("Admin") at the GetMapping and PostMapping part of the controller (AddOrEditController). Now I get this, for example:
Failed to complete request: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
I guess I have to see this.

I just thought that it works. Now it doesn't work with "Admin", either. I get the above mentioned exception.

Smells like the client is not sending a session cookie header, possibly because it’s not receiving or storing one. Is their a JSESSIONID cookie in the browser?

At PostMapping at login I set a session attribute:
CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
session.setAttribute(USER, userDetails.getUser());
Do you think of this one, for example?

First of all, you dont need to define a custom login endpoint, spring will provide the login endpoint for you, as long as you send your username and password as FORM parameters. Second of all if you insist on writing your own login endpoint, you need to understand what the SecurityContext is and that you need to set this manually https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#servlet-authentication-securitycontextholder )you should read this entire page if you seriously want to go down the custom security route)

third, the configure function and the authenticationManagerBean() function are not needed as soon as you have implemented a UserDetailsServiceand annotated it spring security understands you want to use a DaoAuthenticationProvider and instansiates all of this for you and injects your passwordencoder etc. All this is covered in the docs. If you are serious about learning spring security please read the docs! and dont read strange tutorials/youtube videos

fourth, your role is named "ROLE_ADMIN" and you are checking for the role "admin".

Fifth WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is spring 2.x.x and is deprecated since almost 2 years back, please update to spring security 3.x.x and use the latest version.

@Toerktumlare
Thank you for the answers. Apologies, I'm very new to this topic and maybe I wanted to solve this too fast.
To be honest, I used the deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter only, because I had even more problem with the new one.
There is a possibility that I'm checking for the role "admin" but could you please show me where? In my database there are "Admin" and "User" roles only. So, if I'm right there can be "ROLE_Admin" and "ROLE_User" authorities but I can't see "admin". "admin" is only the login / username and also the password of a user with "Admin" role.

I created a CustomSecurityFilter which is always deal with SecurityContext
( SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication); )
And also changed Secured("Admin") to Secured("ROLE_Admin")
It seems to work for now but I guess I have to learn much more.
Thank you for every helps.

Stack overflow is not a forum, this is way too many comments, and it is quite clear that you asked here before spending time reading the official documentation. In the future please read documentation
